# JSON response from other class

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

i have class name

```
public class DriverLocation

{


    public static String[] driverName;
    public static String[] driverCarName;
    public static String[] driverCarModel;
    public static double[] driverLat;
    public static double[] driverLang;

    private JSONArray drivers = null;

    private String json;

    public String URL_ITEMS = "http://steam.com.pk/Nexer/driver.php";
    private static final String TAG_Table_Name = "Driver";
    private static final String TAG_Driver_Name = "driverName";
    private static final String TAG_Driver_Car_Name ="driverCarName";
    private static final String TAG_Driver_Car_Modle = "driverCarModel";
    private static final String TAG_Driver_Lat = "driverLat";
    private static final String TAG_Driver_Lang = "driverLang";

    public DriverLocation(String json) {
        this.json = json;
    }
    public void parJson(){


        JSONObject jsonObject=null;



        try {
            jsonObject=new JSONObject(json);
            drivers=jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_Table_Name);

            driverName = new String[drivers.length()];
            driverCarName = new String[drivers.length()];
            driverCarModel = new String[drivers.length()];
            driverLat = new double[drivers.length()];
            driverLang = new double[drivers.length()];


            for (int i=0;i<drivers.length();i++){
                JSONObject jo=drivers.getJSONObject(i);



                driverName[i]=jo.getString(TAG_Driver_Name);
                driverCarName[i]=jo.getString(TAG_Driver_Car_Name);
                driverCarModel[i]=jo.getString(TAG_Driver_Car_Modle);
                driverLat[i]= jo.getDouble(TAG_Driver_Lat);
                driverLang[i]= jo.getDouble(TAG_Driver_Lang);

            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and a fragment activity where i use volley library in response i receive json array but i dont know how to get values from that array in this activity here is my code for obtaining values from DriverLocation class

```
private void showJSON(String json){
        DriverLocation pj = new DriverLocation(json);
        pj.parJson();

      /*  double[] array={Double.parseDouble("23423.234"), Double.parseDouble("23423.234")};
        double[] array1={Double.parseDouble("23423.234"), Double.parseDouble("23423.234")};
        double[] array2={23423.234,23423.234};
        for (int i=0;i<=array2.length;i++){



        }*/
        for (int i=0;i<=DriverLocation.driverName.length;i++){



        }
```

in the parameter String json i pass my response from volley response listerner
when i just print length i receive correct length but when i want to print driverName from other class its does not return me name . .

```
my Json

{"Driver":[{"driverName":"Naveed","driverCarName":"Honda City","driverCarModel":"2008","driverLat":"33.999253","driverLang ":"71.544465"},{"driverName":"Naveed","driverCarName":"Honda City","driverCarModel":"2008","driverLat":"33.999253","driverLang ":"71.544465"},{"driverName":"Naveed","driverCarName":"Honda City","driverCarModel":"2008","driverLat":"33.999253","driverLang ":"71.544465"}]}
```

Comment: if you are parsing right then you just need to print you `driverName` array and why all arrays are `static`

Comment: please update your question with json response as it's hard to say why it isn't working!

Comment: You'll get a lot of fun with all the static fields (`driverName`, ...)

Comment: when i get length of that array its return me true value but when i want to use actual data from the array its not show me that

Comment: Henry what will be the solution

Comment: can u post your json?so might be able to track error

Comment: i edit my question

Comment: How about you make a Java `Driver` class instead of many String arrays. You could even paste your JSON here. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Create a model class (Bean class) of your JSON response , implement serializable, store data in that object when you get response and then pass that object in second activity...

Comment: What are you getting from Volley JSON? Or Parsed Array? In you code, you posted, your are paring JSON manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would just recommend you look into Retrofit (or at least Gson), and not use static variables at all, and parse your JSON into some custom Java class... etc...

```
private void showJSON(String json){
    DriverLocation pj = new DriverLocation(json); // This does something with 
    pj.parJson(); // This builds some static arrays

    // This loops over an array
    for (int i=0;i<=DriverLocation.driverName.length;i++){
        String name = DriverLocation.driverName[i]; // Gets value
    }
```

Now, of course, you'd have to loop (or directly access) all the other arrays.

---

This is why a Java class would be better, so a `Driver[]`, for example.

```
for (Driver d : DriverLocation.drivers){
    String name = d.getName(); 
}
```

That all is an exercise up to the reader.